# Segmentation error after second user input

Tags: fortran

I compile as such:

```
f77 -c readheader.F
f77 -c readheader2.F
make (for the main program, which is necessary to have a makefile for)
```

and run:

```
./decpar
```

Output:

```
Which datafile?
Point 2a

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory
reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FF5E4A62E08
#1  0x7FF5E4A61F90
#2  0x7FF5E41934AF
#3  0x7FF5E4B25C40
#4  0x7FF5E4B26197
#5  0x7FF5E4B34B87
#6  0x4056B8 in __mysubs2_MOD_readheader2
#7  0x401CA5 in MAIN__ at decpar.F:29 (discriminator 88)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm not going to post the whole code because it's huge and unnecessary. Luckily, the error appears in the first few lines. I have two modules in both of which the user is required to type the name of a datafile so that information is extracted and directed to the main program. I tried to flush(5) the datafile in case for some strange reason it's not overwritten by the second user input and I get "Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.". I tried to change the name of datafile to datafile2 to create new space for the second input, but I get the same problem as when the name is the same. Everything I have tried stops at 'Point 2a'. Also, if I switch the order of the modules call, the problem persists in the second file. After more trying gfortran -c -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all, the error I got was:
Fortran runtime error: Index '1' of dimension 1 of array 'thetax' above upper bound of 0.

P.S.: Some commands that are not indented properly are just written as such, for formatting purposes here.

```
  module MySubs
  contains

  subroutine readheader(theta,thetax,thetay,thetaz)

  include 'psize.inc'
  include 'pinfo.inc'
  #include "rvarrays.inc"
  include 'itype.inc'
  include 'iodefs.inc'

  REAL,ALLOCATABLE, intent(inout), DIMENSION (:) :: thetay, thetaz
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE, intent(inout), DIMENSION (:) :: theta, thetax

  ALLOCATE (theta(nobj),thetax(nobj),thetay(nobj),thetaz(nobj))

  1    print*,'Which datafile?'
  read(*,'(a)') datafile 

  CALL readdata

  do i=1,nobj
    if (i.LT.nobj) then
        thetax(i)=(v(1,i+1)-v(1,i))*(r(1,i+1)-r(1,i))**(-1)
        thetay(i)=(v(2,i+1)-v(2,i))*(r(2,i+1)-r(2,i))**(-1)
        thetaz(i)=(v(3,i+1)-v(3,i))*(r(3,i+1)-r(3,i))**(-1)
        theta(i)=thetax(i)+thetay(i)+thetaz(i)
        else 
        thetax(i)=(v(1,i)-v(1,i-1))*(r(1,i)-r(1,i-1))**(-1)
        thetay(i)=(v(2,i)-v(2,i-1))*(r(2,i)-r(2,i-1))**(-1)
        thetaz(i)=(v(3,i)-v(3,i-1))*(r(3,i)-r(3,i-1))**(-1)
        theta(i)=thetax(i)+thetay(i)+thetaz(i)
    endif 
  end do
  RETURN
  end subroutine readheader

  end module MySubs
```

---

```
  module MySubs2
  contains

  subroutine readheader2(thetapx, thetapy, thetapz,thetap)

  include 'psize.inc'
  include 'pinfo.inc'
  #include "rvarrays.inc"
  include 'itype.inc'
  include 'iodefs.inc'

  character*1 answer
  REAL :: z2
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,intent(inout),DIMENSION (:) :: thetapz,thetap
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,intent(inout),DIMENSION (:) :: thetapx, thetapy
  ALLOCATE (thetapx(nobj),thetapy(nobj),thetapz(nobj))


  1    print*,'Which datafile?'
  print*, 'Point 2a'
  read(*,'(a)') datafile
  print*, 'Point 2b'
  CALL readdata

 do i=1,nobj

  if (i<nobj) then
    thetapx(i)=(v(1,i+1)-v(1,i))*(r(1,i+1)-r(1,i))**(-1)
    thetapy(i)=(v(2,i+1)-v(2,i))*(r(2,i+1)-r(2,i))**(-1)
        thetapz(i)=(v(3,i+1)-v(3,i))*(r(3,i+1)-r(3,i))**(-1)
        thetap(i)=thetapx(i)+thetapy(i)+thetapz(i)
  else 
    thetapx(i)=(v(1,i)-v(1,i-1))*(r(1,i)-r(1,i-1))**(-1)
    thetapy(i)=(v(2,i)-v(2,i-1))*(r(2,i)-r(2,i-1))**(-1)
        thetapz(i)=(v(3,i)-v(3,i-1))*(r(3,i)-r(3,i-1))**(-1)
        thetap(i)=thetapx(i)+thetapy(i)+thetapz(i)
  endif 

 end do

  RETURN
  end subroutine readheader2

  end module MySubs2
```

---

```
  PROGRAM decpar

  use MySubs
  use MySubs2

  include 'psize.inc'
  include 'pinfo.inc'
  #include "rvarrays.inc"
  include 'itype.inc'
  include 'iodefs.inc'

  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: dztheta,dthetax,dthetay,dthetaz
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: convtheta,dttheta,q1,q2,q3,q
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: theta,thetax,thetay,thetaz
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: thetapx, thetapy, thetapz,thetap
  REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: dthetasp

  ALLOCATE(dztheta(nobj),dthetax(nobj),dthetay(nobj),dthetaz(nobj))
  ALLOCATE(q(nobj),dthetasp(nobj),q3(nobj))
  ALLOCATE(convtheta(nobj),dttheta(nobj),q1(nobj),q2(nobj))

  CALL readheader(theta,thetax,thetay,thetaz)
  CALL readheader2(thetapx, thetapy, thetapz,thetap)

  q0=-0.55
  do i=1,nobj
    dztheta(i)=(thetap(i)-theta(i))*(z1-z2)**(-1)
    dttheta(i)=-(2./3.)*dztheta(i)
    if (i<nobj) then
       dthetax(i)=r(1,i)*(thetax(i+1)-thetax(i))/(r(1,i+1)-r(1,i))
       dthetay(i)=r(2,i)*(thetay(i+1)-thetay(i))/(r(2,i+1)-r(2,i))
       dthetaz(i)=r(3,i)*(thetaz(i+1)-thetaz(i))/(r(3,i+1)-r(3,i))
       dthetasp(i)=dthetax(i)+dthetay(i)+dthetaz(i)
    else 
       dthetax(i)=r(1,i)*(thetax(i)-thetax(i-1))/(r(1,i)-r(1,i-1))
       dthetay(i)=r(2,i)*(thetay(i)-thetay(i-1))/(r(2,i)-r(2,i-1))
       dthetaz(i)=r(3,i)*(thetaz(i)-thetaz(i-1))/(r(3,i)-r(3,i-1))
       dthetasp(i)=dthetax(i)+dthetay(i)+dthetaz(i)
    endif
  convtheta(i)=dttheta(i)+h100*100.0*dthetasp(i)  
  q1(i)=-1+(1+q0)*(1+theta(i)/(3.0*100.0*h100))**(-2)
  q2(i)=-(dttheta(i)/(3*100*h100)**2)
  q3(i)=(1+theta(i)/(3*100*h100))**(-2)
  q(i)=q1(i)+q2(i)*q3(i)
  end do

  DEALLOCATE(dztheta,dthetax,dthetay,dthetaz)
  DEALLOCATE(q,q1,q2,q3,dthetasp)
  DEALLOCATE(convtheta,dttheta)

  end
```

Comment: Try to compile the `readheader...` also with debug options (and boundary checking options). write out also the result of the read statement directly after the read statement. Try to make a small program that also shows the same problem.

Comment: Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Your code is certainly not Fortran 77, it is a much more recent standard. The fact that you are using a `f77` command is completely irrelevant, it probably just points to `gfortran` or some other compiler (please specify). We need a [mcve] from you. Compile your code with all debuggings flags you can (for example, `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all`).

Comment: I used f77, because that was the only option for the "SYS" configuration when I installed the code. Anyway, I ran again using the debugging flags you suggested and I am getting: Fortran runtime error: Index '1' of dimension 1 of array 'thetax' above upper bound of 0. I suppose that I am exceeding my stack size, but I have no clue as to how this can be fixed.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain the **complete** error message. It is **not** stacksize, it is a programming mistake. The program is accessing an array outside of the bounds. Do not forget the [mcve], notice the words **minimal** and **complete**.

Comment: @VladimirF That's the complete error message I am getting though, nothing more than that. I will also edit my question to make it complete, as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: The example should be compilable. Copy and paste the code in such a way that it is formatted properly. It does matter, because you are using fixed form source form. The indentation is important. If you don't know how, you can add a comment starting at the first column anywhere in the file. Anyway, your code is **very** far from complete. Notice how many include files would would need to have to be able to compile it. See https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Also use 'implicit none' in your code.

Comment: @VladimirF It's not enough to upload the respective files cause they are linked in a super complex way, where, changing the path would cause them not to run. This is just a small part I wrote in someone else's code. So I cannot post the whole code or the other files. From what you can tell, is there something blatantly wrong with my programming? Sorry for making it too difficult, but the circumstances do not allow me to share more.

Comment: @albert but there are variables implicitly declared in other files. if i used implicit none that would make me need to declare all the variables included in every linked file, isn't it?

Comment: That would be good practice.

Comment: @That's why you should start preparing the [mcve] (did you really read the link?) A MCVE is not jsut uploading loads of code (see https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ ) You reaally should make your own effort to isolate the problem into a smaller code example. It is not supposed to be easy, but it is necessary.

Comment: You still didn't even include the new error message into the question.

Comment: @VladimirF Did you see my answer? I said that that was the only output on my screen.

Comment: I saw your comment, but you did NOT put it **into the question**. Important information should always go into the question, not into the comments below. The comments below can be deleted any time without notice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a guess, assuming that the code is right. You have a call to the C pre-processor with the line

```
#include "rvarrays.inc"
```

probably there is some array defined in there. Without the `-cpp` flag in

```
f77 -c readheader.F
f77 -c readheader2.F
```

the include doesn't work and the arrays are not not defined. But since you do not have `implicit none` the name of those array are still valid names, but for a scalars. Try adding the flag, or removing the # for a Fortran include.

On the other hand you should get a compile error from the # without the `-cpp` flag...

Comment: If it is gfortran, and it looks like that (the OP sis not respond to my request for clarification), than cpp is run automatically for any capital F extension. The same holds for most other compilers. One would expect very different (and catastrophic) error messages if the cpp wasn't run.

Comment: We really should avoid answering incomplete questions by such guessing.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the F. It's a fun challenge, but I know you are right @VladimirF

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I figured out the problem on my own, cause it was literally impossible to have you install the code (since that's what was required, even if I uploaded all the files - which I couldn't cause that was someone else's property). My arrays seemed to be allocated, but they were not; The program did not know at that point the value of 'nobj'. So, putting all ALLOCATE statements after the CALLs, solved the problem!

Comment: That is why vladimirF and I already wrote about using debug flags  (-fcheck=all, -g etc.) this would probably have given you an easy indication about what went wrong.

Comment: You are **never** supposed to upload all files. You are supposed to isolate a **minimal** example that easily fits into the question. The fact is that one very often finds the error oneself during the process of isolating the [mcve]. I am still conviced you did not even bother to read the link.

Comment: @albert I used them and it's just that the error message remains the same as I already said two times above

Comment: Wel you solved the problem so hat is OK but it remains strange that the error message remains the same even with the advised debugging flags (I would have expected at least an out of bound message with a line number)..

Comment: @albert There was indeed an error message and it is in the comments: *"Fortran runtime error: Index '1' of dimension 1 of array 'thetax' above upper bound of 0. "* My repeated request to put this (and the complete context) into the question was just ignored.

Comment: @VladimirF I apologize for not including it. I understand your reaction, but in order for a community to work, it takes effort from both sides. I am not going to lay down all the circumstances that kept me from including the error on time and properly, but I think that politeness is imperative in all cases. If you think that my question is not phrased well enough and that I am not following your advice, then don't spend time answering or close the thread if you're an admin. Spending time only to be judgy and ironic, does not help anyone.